# adding JLabel properties to anonymous variable types?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I'm trying to add borders to JLabels but I don't have names for them, they're created within a loop and the "this" keyword does not do what I want.

```
for(int i = 1; i < first; i++){
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        dayBoxes.add(new JLabel(""));   
    }
```

I want the blank JLables to have properties beyond just having no text.

If the JLabels all had names I could easily do name.setBorder but that isn't the case here and I think it would be very inefficient to name them all in an array. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i < first; i++) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    dayBoxes.add(label);   
}
```

Comment: Lol, its been one of those days. Thanks.